# How to fix "no such file or directory, lstat 'scss/'"?

Tags: css, json, npm, sass, visual-studio-code

i'm trying to follow a simple tutorial on youtupe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYzHS-n2gqU&t=900s where he is tring to run an npm  scripts "sass" file using the tirminal.

-When i execut the command **npm run sass**  shows me an error message 
**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'scss/'**

-I think the problem with the **path of file or permissions on the file**, where should configure in way to looks in the correct director.

- here is [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG082.png)

-When i replace the script with :

```
"scripts": {
    **"sass": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" "**
  },
```

it work fine.
,but

```
"scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive" 
  },
```

give me an error.
 package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "abrahem_portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "PortFolio",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    **"sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive"**

  },
  "author": "Abrahem Gh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0"
  }
}
```

-As the tutorial point that the terminal should show this:

> abrahem_portfolio@1.0.0 sass C:\Users\Abrahim\Abrahem_portfolio
>   node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive

-but it shows an error:

> abrahem_portfolio@1.0.0 sass C:\Users\Abrahim\Abrahem_portfolio
>   node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive

```
fs.js:114
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'scss/'
    at Object.lstatSync (fs.js:845:3)
    at Object.module.exports.parseDir (C:\Users\Abrahim\Abrahem_portfolio\node_modules\sass-graph\sass-graph.js:153:10)
    at Object.watcher.reset (C:\Users\Abrahim\Abrahem_portfolio\node_modules\node-sass\lib\watcher.js:17:21)
    at watch (C:\Users\Abrahim\Abrahem_portfolio\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:260:20)
    at run (C:\Users\Abrahim\Abrahem_portfolio\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:319:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Abrahim\Abrahem_portfolio\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:405:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! abrahem_portfolio@1.0.0 sass: `node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the abrahem_portfolio@1.0.0 sass script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abrahim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-25T07_38_42_251Z-debug.log
```

The project structure looks like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG082.png

Comment: Could you show us the folder structure?

Comment: listen what he says around 16:00 "SCSS the directory we just created"

Comment: Could you add the screenshot of your project setup to the post? This would speed up the helping process @rioV8

Comment: @MaartenDev https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG082.png

Comment: Did the answer help solve your problem?

Comment: @MaartenDev  I want  to say thanks for help but this tip pop up in my face 
 "Use comments to ask for more information or suggestion improvement. Avoid comments like "+1" or thanks", thanks for help dude,  Could help me in other thing plz, in same [video]  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HguAyYnWBuU&t=294s) , "he is trying to use icon form fontawesome " and it work for me , but it take a bit of time(+2 sec) to load the icon, any idea why and how to resolve ?

Comment: @AbrahemGh If the solution below helped solve the problem please mark it is such, this way other people can find it. You are correct about not stating thanks in the comments

Comment: You can add the following snippet: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`  to the `head` element @AbrahemGh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at your folder structure you can spot that the

```
"scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive" 
  },
```

command looks for a folder named `scss` but in your project structure you have a folder called `sass`
This error can thus be solved by renaming the `sass` folder to `scss`.

The following solution would fix the problem:

```
"scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -w sass/ -o dist/css/ --recursive" 
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working after write full path

"sass": "node-sass --watch public/user/assets/scss/main.scss public/user/assets/css/style.css"